# Docsign, SharePoint and Nintex

Tags: sharepoint-2013, docusignapi

I have a DocuSign Trial on an Office365 site with Nintex. I am trying to use a Nintex workflow to send a document within a document library when the document has changed.

I get the following error and no further insight:

> An exception occurred while processing parameter [InputFileToSign]

Any URLS, tutorials, cookbooks orsamples on this would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for general help or recommendations are off topic for Stack Overflow. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to figure it out for yourself. If you have a *specific* question, it should include a summary of what you have tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing could be a result of not defining the template ID or envelop in DocuSign that you want to send to the user. Suggest making sure the template exists in DocuSign first, and the account you are using in the workflow action has access to that template. You can also reference a file from a SharePoint library to send via DocuSign which should go through as long as you provide a name, email and message body.